# How to average the difference between 2 rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

No rush, this is pure curiosity as i've already finished the project but i want to know if there's a faster and cleaner way of averaging the difference between 2 rows.

I have 2 rows of data and i need to average the difference between the 2.

i.e.

```
Row1  5 6 8 4    
Row2  4 7 8 9
```

what i want to average

```
1,-1,0,-5
```

I tried this formula but failed.

```
{=AVERAGE(G26:U26-G28:U28)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Average of the differences is equal to the difference of the averages, so

```
=AVERAGE(Row1)-AVERAGE(Row2)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: OMG, i am a complete idiot.  this is what happens when you go into a mode and forget basic math.  thanks good sir.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:D1-A2:D2)/COLUMNS(A1:D1)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks scott, sorry again about skipping your answer.  it's just that xidgel gave me a much more logical solution.  logical meaning duh this is like 6th grade math stuff.  this is what happens when you get tunnel vision

Comment: @SantaSecrets no apologies needed, it is a better approach.